# HTTP query string semicolon parameters separation

Tags: web-services, http, query-string, http-get

HTML 4.01 specification ([B.2.2 Ampersands in URI attribute values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2)) recommends HTTP servers to accept semicolon (`;`) as a parameter separator (for which ampersand `&` is in use).

Is any server supporting it? Is anyone using this? Is it worth to bother with that when considering allowed formats of query string for a web service?

Comment: This question arose from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920242/http-query-and-uri-encoding-doubts after a suggestion of splitting it into smaller questions.