# National characters in URI

Tags: url, encoding, uri, urlencode, url-encoding

How should authors publish (by URI) resources with names containing non-ASCII (for example national) characters?

Considering all the various parties (HTML code, browser sending request, browser saving file do disk, server receiving and processing request and server storing the file) all (possibly) using various encodings it seems nearly impossible to have it working consistently. Or at least I never managed.

When it comes to web pages I’m already used to that and always replace national characters with corresponding Latin base characters.

But when it comes to external files (PDFs, images, …) it somehow “feels wrong” to “downgrade” the names. Especially if one expects users to save those files on disk. How to deal with this issue?

Comment: This question arose from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920242/http-query-and-uri-encoding-doubts after a suggestion of splitting it into smaller questions.